# Linq to Entities doesn't return same value as foreach

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

*Note: I am using EF 6.1.2*

I have a database with Transactions that will be available on a particular date. I have a method that is supposed to return the currently available balance, but when run in EF it returns a different value than if run normally...

My Entity class looks like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AmountInCents { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

This method returns the correct available amount:

```
double GetAvailableBalance(DbProxy dbProxy, DateTimeOffset atTime)
{
    var amount = 0d;
    var transactions = dbProxy.Transactions.ToList();
    foreach (var transaction in transactions)
    {
        if (transaction.DateAvailable <= atTime)
        {
            amount += transaction.AmountInCents/100d;
        }
    }
}
```

This version returns 0:

```
double GetAvailableBalance(DbProxy dbProxy, DateTimeOffset atTime)
{
    return await dbProxy.Transactions
        .Where(t => t.DateAvailable <= atTime)
        .Select(t => t.AmountInCents / 100d)
        .Union(new[] { 0d })
        .SumAsync();
}
```

I'm pretty stumped why this isn't working... Can anyone see what the issue might be?

Comment: Do you have values above 100 in there, or are all of them less than 100?

Comment: why are you unioning with zero? a sum of an empty sequence will return 0 anyway

Comment: A union will remove dupes. Probably not what you want.

Comment: as a side note, anything dealing with currency (which needs to be absolutely precise!) should be using `decimal` (`m`) instead of `double` (`d`)

Comment: @Shoe, I think you're onto something...

Comment: @DLeh, Not true, Sum will throw in EF if the sequence is empty

Comment: try using `Concat(new[] { 0d })` instead

Comment: @DLeh For Linq to SQL an empty sequence will not return 0. It will throw exception or return null of summing a nullable column.

Comment: @DLeh, you got it... I was getting Union & Concat mixed up... That fixed it! Throw it in an answer and I'll give you some imaginary internet points

Comment: Or, you know, use `.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union with 0 is what's causing the issue. You should change this to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` or you could do `Concat(new[] { 0 })` instead.

Again, I'd like to stress that you should probably be using `decimal` if you're dealing with dollar amounts, otherwise you may encounter wonky math operations that could result in real money being unaccounted for or lost.

```
double GetAvailableBalance(DbProxy dbProxy, DateTimeOffset atTime)
{
    return await dbProxy.Transactions
        .Where(t => t.DateAvailable <= atTime)
        .Select(t => t.AmountInCents / 100d)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .SumAsync();
}

double GetAvailableBalance(DbProxy dbProxy, DateTimeOffset atTime)
{
    return await dbProxy.Transactions
        .Where(t => t.DateAvailable <= atTime)
        .Select(t => t.AmountInCents / 100d)
        .Concat(new[] { 0 })
        .SumAsync();
}
```

If you must use doubles, you should at least convert to a double as the last step:

```
    return await dbProxy.Transactions
        .Where(t => t.DateAvailable <= atTime)
        .Select(t => t.AmountInCents)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .SumAsync() / 100d;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using decimal. These methods (and any others that convert to fractional dollars) are actually only for display purposes. All operations on amounts are done in cents using INT.

Comment: okay, just be aware that even `Sum`s on those doubles could be faulty. You should sum the ints and then `/ 100d` for the most accurate double amount.